# Are there any other methods for a marketplace with direct-to-seller payment other than Amazon Flexible Payment Services (FPS)?

Tags: credit-card, frame-rate, marketplace

Amazon [Flexible Payment Services](http://aws.amazon.com/fps/) has functionality built in to allow sellers to receive payment directly into their Amazon Payments Business account rather than going to the marketplace owner.  (See this [marketplace example](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/business?sn=devfps/marketplace).)  This money can then be withdrawn at the leisure of the seller.

The nice thing about this setup is that I, as the marketplace owner, don't have to hassle with monthly payouts to my sellers.  Plus, the seller has the piece of mind to withdraw the funds whenever.

1) Do you know of any other places that offer this functionality?

2) Or do you have any other ideas for how I could reduce the hassle of doing monthly payouts to the sellers?

Comment: EDIT: I should note that FPS allows the marketplace owner, me, to take a fee for every transaction.  I'm also looking for that ability too.

Answer (score 1):

That is Adaptive payment in paypal.
Have a look at:https://www.x.com/community/ppx/adaptive_payments

Answer (score 0):

Paypal has this.

Comment: Does this PayPal service allow me to take a cut of the purchase?